# Wordpress 403/404 Errors: You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/themes.php on this server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Some background:

I setup six blogs this week, all using Wordpress 2.92, installed with Fantastico on a baby croc plan with Hostgator.

I used the same theme (heatmap 2.5.4) and plugins for each blog.

They were all up and running, no issues at all.

I go to create a new blog this morning, using the same setup, and when I try to change the theme settings, I get the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/themes.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.8n DAV/2 mod_fcgid/2.3.5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at http://www.mydomain.com Port 80
```

I tried uninstalling WP and doing a clean install, still the same issue with a clean installation.

So I went back and checked the six other blogs that I had setup over the last week or so, and they are also now giving me 403 or 404 errors when trying to change theme settings, and everytime there's an error it points to either themes.php or functions.php

At this point I'm at my wits end trying to figure out what the problem is. Hostgator support looked at it and thought maybe it was a permissions issue but they reset those and I'm still having the problem.

At first I thought the problem might have been related to a plugin I recently installed on the previous six blogs that morning (ByREV Fix Missed Shedule Plugin) to deal with a missed schedule bug with WP 2.92, and that maybe that had mucked things up. But then I checked a blog I built months ago, also using the same theme and plugins, and now it too is also encountering the same problem.

Any ideas? I tried deleting my htaccess, uploading a blank one, uploading one with this snippet I found on the hostgator forum:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Nothing has worked. I still get 403 or 404 errors everytime. Everything was working perfectly yesterday so I know this setup DOES WORK, I've just mucked something up somewhere and I'm clueless what it is.

I read a related thread here and tried chmoding the wp-content folder to 0755 and still having the issue.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: have you checked all .htaccess files(there may be more than one) and they cascade from the root down.
Have you made any other changes to your install, plugins etc.

Comment: The only change I made after installing the previous six blogs and before creating the new blog was to install a plugin that checks for posts that have missed their scheduled posting time/date, and forces them to go ahead and be published.  I installed that plugin on all six blogs because there is a bug in WP 2.92 that was causing missed posts.

Comment: I'm not sure how that plugin accomplishes what it does, maybe it changed some permissions somewhere? I checked a blog I installed months ago, that DOESN'T have the missed schedule plugin, but does use the same theme, and it also encounters an error when accessing themes.php

I checked for htaccess files, is it necessary for there to be more than one, or should there just be one for my root domain?

Comment: you aren't required to have any .htaccess file, but you can also have one in every directory from the root directory down entries further down the directory structure overide those above. 

I am assuming the other blog that you checked is on the same server.

Comment: I backed up the .htaccess file from my root domain, and deleted it along with the htaccess from one of the domains I'm having issues with, and the problem is still the same (404 error when trying to change theme settings, which accesses wp-admin/themes.php)

Comment: Deativate *all* plugins and see what happens.

Comment: Same thing.  This is a brand new WP installation, not even akismet is on.

Comment: Sounds like Hostgator made a server config change. Set up a new - and as simple as possible - WP install and test it. If it works OK, then start adding plugins and the theme you want to use, one thing at a time.

Comment: I'm noticing that some php files in the WP installation are 0644 while others are 0755, is that normal?

Comment: Did you try songdogtech's suggestion regarding setting the directory permissions? Have you checked the file permissions on themes.php. I would also try disabling the plugin. When setting permissions rather than using your ftp client log into your HostGator account via SSH. You may need to open a ticket to enable this if you haven't already.

Comment: Yes when I cmod to 777, it wouldnt even allow me to login to WP, just gives 500 internal error.

Comment: Okay, so I deleted the add on domain, re added it, installed a fresh WP, and installed a different theme to try and duplicate the issue and I've been unable to.  The new theme also has a "theme options" page which accesses /wp-admin/themes.php?page=functions.php and doesn't give a 404 error so at this point I'm wondering if it really is the other theme causing the problem.  I'm still at a loss as to how though.  Appreciate all the help guys, I think at this point I just need to change themes but I'm not sure whether there will still be an unresolved issue or if it is just this theme.

Comment: you may want to compare the directory and file permissions between the working and one of the non working installs.

I would be a little leery of a theme that had this effect - would love to know what theme and where you got it from.

Comment: It's the "Heatmap" theme, installed directly from within WP using their themes finder.  The most frustrating thing is I have about a dozen blogs in all using this exact same setup, half were made months ago and I haven't touched them since, as they are already setup the way I want.  And yet when I logged into them today after discovering the issue with the new blogs, they also encounter the same 404 error when trying to change theme options.  I was changing those very options less than 24 hours ago on a blog and it worked perfectly, now overnight it's broken.

Comment: I don't really know much about themes.  I wonder if Heatmap interacts with WP in a way that Hostgator no longer allows because of a server change? I'm still trying to duplicate the problem with other themes but nothing is producing a 404.

Comment: what happens if you switch a working install to that theme? does it return a 404? maybe it was an incomplete theme install or a missed setup option?

Comment: For what it is worth the heatmap theme appears to be a beta.

Comment: I'm using the 2.5.4 version which has been out awhile.  This is the first time in about 6 months I've run into issues with it.  Anyway I just installed it on a blog that has never run that theme, and when I switch to Heatmap and attempt to change any heatmap theme options, I get the 404.  Looks like I'm off to find a new theme.  Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: Hope that helped, but I still think it's a Hostgator permissions issue and not .htaccess, something they either changed recently or has bene there all along. If Steve and I helped, you should uptick our answers, or accept them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error you're getting - permissions - is the most indicative. Bump wp-content and wp-admin to 777 and try it, and if it works, then change them both back to 755 and see if it still works. What are you using to change folder permissions? An FTP client?

Comment: I'm using FireFTP for Firefox as an FTP client.  When I change permissions, it gives me the option to change permissions for just that directory, but also sub directories and all content.  Should I be changing permissions for all content?

I changed both including contents to 777, now I receive a 500 internal server error when trying to login to Wordpress.

Comment: No, not contents too, but that can be changed later. 500 errors are from your .htaccess; how are you editing that? With a plain text editor? 500 errors can be caused by using the wrong character encoding in your text editor. If you just changed .htaccess and didn't update permalinks within WP admin, that can mean your permalinks are set to one thing in the WP database and another in .htaccess. Delete .htaccess to get rid of the 500 errors and see where you are.

Comment: I used notepad when I edited it.  When I first started investigating this problem, the htaccess had the # Begin wordpress and #end wordpress, but nothing inbetween.  The file was blank otherwise.  I've backed up and deleted all htaccess I could find from the root domain on down to the domain where the WP installation is hosted but still have the original issue with a 404.

Comment: I don't think these are .htaccess permissions problem, because I got the same error on my WordPress installs (running on a VPS I administer) and the permissions had nothing to do with it; it was the <IfModule> statement looking for a `.c` module, when it should have been looking for a `.so` module. I don't know why it failed over into a 403 error, but for me that was exactly the problem. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9050019/362042

Comment: Never recommend 777, learn how permissions work, and fix it correctly.

Comment: @Aaron: read what I wrote: "Bump wp-content and wp-admin to 777 and try it, and if it works, then *change them both back to 755*." This is a common fix for some permission problems where the user/group needs to be toggled. It's even suggested by core WP devs at wordpress.org. Why are you cruising two year old threads to downvote?

Comment: @songdogtech I had a problem with 403 errors and this came up. Either 755 works or it doesn't. In fact, it can't not work, if all you need is for apache to read the file. 750 with the group set to apache (or www-data, depending on distro) should be fine. Giving global write access never makes sense.

Answer (score 21):

A few years late, but I have a solution for the most recent version of WordPress, which has this same issue (WordPress-generated .htaccess files break sites, reuslting in 403 Forbidden error messages). Here's that it looks like when WordPress creates it:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The problem is that the  conditional doesn't work. It doesn't work because the module it's looking for isn't `.c`, it's `.so`. I think this is a platform-specific, or configuration-specific issue, where Mac OS and Lunix Apache installations are set up for `.so` AKA 'shared-object' modules. Looking for a `.c` module shouldn't break the conditional, I think that's a bug, but it's the issue.

Simply change the `mod_rewrite.c` to `mod_rewrite.so` and you're all set to go!

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.so>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: please don't use this on multisite

Answer (score 3):

We found the asnwer of at techieshelp..its the htaccess thats the issue...

http://www.techieshelp.com/you-don%E2%80%99t-have-permission-to-access-wp-adminpost-php-on-this-server/

Answer (score 2):

Just to follow up, problem solved! I mentioned mod_sec settings for my server as being the possible culprit as suggested and they were able to fix this issue.  Here's what the tech agent said to tell them when you go to support:

> Just let them know you need the rule
>   340163 whitelisted for domain.com as
>   its hitting a mod_sec rule.

Apparently you will need to do this for each domain that is having the issue, but it works.  Thanks for all the suggestions everyone!

Comment: Thanks Glen. I was experiencing a similar problem and I contacted hostgator and they said that they did some kind of mod seucrity upgrade and that they white listed the domain. But he also indicated that it should fix everything in that one cpanel account.

Comment: Thank you, had the same problem and your answer made me communicate with my hosting providers. This is exactly what the representative mentioned to me - "LiveSupport_t3: Sorry you do not have shell access and i have done mode security setting for your issue"

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck bud...I had the same issue but had more tech knowledge on the matter and was able to determine that it was a mod_sec issue that hostgator has to fix/whitelist on their own. You cannot do it yourself. Simply ask the hostgator tech to check mod_sec settings on your server.

Enjoy your fixed issue ;D

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<Directory /path/to/your/wp-admin>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: So I should create an htaccess using that? Where should I upload it, to the root of the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully people will find this answer as there are many, many posts about this on the web. Many people suggested it was an .htaccess problem, and for me it was. However, I had been looking in the .htaccess in the root, not in the .htaccess in the wp-admin folder.
Normally, I work on this site in particular through terminal services, so when it booted me and I couldn't log back in, I was trying to access it from my home computer (and it's IP).

Silly me forgot the IP restriction I had placed in the wp-admin .htaccess file.

```
AuthName "Protected"
AuthType Basic
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 11.11.11.11
</Limit>
```

If you have something like this in your wp-admin .htaccess files, that would easily explain why all the sites you work on ceased to function at the same time. Internet providers occasionally rotate IPs so that nobody is running a server from home without paying for it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but nothing above worked...try a really simple solution...

Back up your .htaccess file. Delete it from your root directory. Then try accessing those directories. Its likely that whatever rewrite conditions you had in your file were causing those access issues. The index page should be picked up automatically on most hosts. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable ModSecurity from your cPanel. 
Log into your cPanel. Find the category "Security". There you can find ModSecurity link.Click on it and disable it for the domain you are facing the 403 error.

Some 403 errors can be solved by this method too. Go to the wordpress dashboard, settings>permalink and just click save.

Hope this helped. :)