# jQuery cycle breaking in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

Any ideas as to why the jQuery Cycle plugin would function perfectly on a local install of wordpress and is now broken running on a live server? I have referenced all of my javascript files in the wordpress header and all of my cycle functions are written in "custom.js". I understand that it is best practice to include these in the footer but this seemed to give me errors.

http://sameralmadani.com/aleo_retouching/?page_id=6

Any clue as to why the `.cycle()` plugin is getting ignored would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site apparently doesn't have access to the location where your "cycle" and "easing" js is located.

It's giving a "403 Forbidden" error. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: Here's a screen capture of the console after I load your page. http://screencast.com/t/QQF7RwuR

Comment: I had to change permissions on these particular files from 705 to 644 using my FTP client. Not sure why these two particular files had different permissions set when all of my other .js files were already set to 644. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your server/ftp settings.
You don't have access to http://sameralmadani.com/aleo_retouching/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js because of a 403 error.

Set the /wp-content folder (recursive) to CHMOD 777. If this works, set CHMOD back to 755 and check if it works too.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785552/1184904 for further information

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the WordPress plugin version of cycle? Have you specified the parent container's id name in the control panel? If you just migrated your site to a new url that information may not have been retained.

Comment: I'm not using the wordpress plugin version. I am using the minified cycle plugin.